# Laravel input is not being passed to controller

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, backend

i was trying to pass an input to a function which is update in this case.The thing is that whenever I submit the form I don't receive this specific input so I tried many stuff one of them is that I have created a test input and I was able to receive it correctly in `$request`.
also tried changing its name to say quantity for this example but it didn't work.
please check my code and tell me if I am missing something.Thanks alot.

front-end

```
<form action="/shopping-cart/update/{{$product->item_id}}/{{$product->id}}" method="post">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
                        <input type="text" name="test_input">
                    <div class="input-group number-spinner" style="border:solid 1px; width:120px;">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="subtract({{$product->id}})">-</button>
                        </span>
                        <!-- problemetic input -->
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" style="border:0;background-color:#ddc2b1" 
                            name="quantity {{$product->id}}" value="{{$product->quantity}}" id="quantity {{$product->id}}" disabled>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="add({{$product->id}})">+</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

route

```
Route::PUT('/shopping-cart/update/{item_id}/{product_id}', 'ShoppingCartController@update');
```

update function

```
public function update($item_id , $product_id, Request $request)
{
    $cart_item = ShoppingCart::find($item_id);
    $cart_item->quantity = $request->input('quantity '.$product_id);
    dd($request);
    return redirect('/shopping-cart/view');
}
```

$request
[image]

Comment: I'm sure the input is being passed. Can you try `dd($request->all());`

Comment: unfortunately the same result is being displayed with only the method , token and the test input.

Comment: Okay, I see it now, the input is not being passed because the input is `disabled`. Remove the `disabled` attribute in the input

Comment: Or you can change `disabled` to `readonly` if you don't want the field editable.

Comment: also  `name="quantity {{$product->id}}"`: no spaces only underscores

Comment: problem solved thank you all. actually in order to traingulate the cause of the issue i tried each solution one by one and i found out that spaces are allowed actually so if i put the name with underscore or with a space it is completly fine and in the backend an under score will be added automatically so putting underscore is a good practice. the main reason was because the field was disabled when changed to read only i recieved the data correctly. @aceraven777 if you would like you could make a detailed answer for everyone else if they face the same problem and i will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

1. Your input naming. In your frontend view you name your input `name="quantity {{$product->id}}"` which has a space on it. Either you remove the space or replace it with `_`.
2. Your input attribute is `disabled`. Disabled inputs are not passed to the controller. If you want it NOT editable and still want to pass the value, you can use the `readonly` attribute.

So in order to solve your problem you change the input to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" style="border:0;background-color:#ddc2b1" 
    name="quantity_{{$product->id}}" value="{{$product->quantity}}" id="quantity_{{$product->id}}" readonly>
```